# after filtering data from Firestore using a PickerViewer i'm not able to send the data to another VC

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, uipickerview

i have a `UIPickerViewer` with 3 lines, after querying data from `Firestore` i want to be able to send the results to `TableView` in another VC. Segue works but no data is transferred. Not sure what i'm missing or what i'm doing wrong. Thank you!

i'm able to retrieve data from `Firestore` to a `TableView` directly, but, when i filter the data using the `PickerView`, i cannot send the results to a `TableView` on a separate VC.

```
    @IBAction func getDataTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()

    if HOSP != (hospnameTxt.text!) {
        query = 
Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("hosp", 
isEqualTo: (hospnameTxt.text!))
    } else if TEAM != teamnameTxt.text {
        query = 
Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("team", 
isEqualTo: (teamnameTxt.text!))
    } else if ASSIGNEDMD != provnameTxt.text {
        query = 
Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("assignedmd", 
isEqualTo: (provnameTxt.text!))

    }

    query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let assigneddate = data[ASSIGNEDDATE] as? String ?? ""
                let assignedmd = data[ASSIGNEDMD] as? String ?? ""
                let officemd = data[OFFICEMD] as? String ?? ""
                let ptname = data[PTNAME] as? String ?? ""
                let room = data[ROOM] as? String ?? ""
                let seenosee = data[SEENOSEE] as? String ?? ""

                let newPtList = PTList(assigneddate: assigneddate, 
assignedmd: assignedmd, officemd: officemd, ptname: ptname, room: 
room, seenosee: seenosee)
                self.ptlists.append(newPtList)
                print(document.data())
            }
            //self.TableView.reloadData()
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoresults", sender: self)

    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoresults" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! resultsdataVC
        vc.ptlists = ptlists
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
}
```

**resultsdataVC**

```
class resultsdataVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var ptlist: PTList!
var ptlists = [PTList]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return ptlists.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"ptlistCell", for: indexPath)
        as? ptlistCell {
        cell.configureCell(ptlist: ptlists[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
  }
}
```

**ptlistCell**

```
class ptlistCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet private weak var ptnameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var assignedmdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var officemdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var roomnumberLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var seenoseeLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var assigneddateLbl: UILabel!

private var ptlist: PTList!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

func configureCell(ptlist: PTList) {

    ptnameLbl.text = ptlist.ptname
    assignedmdLbl.text = ptlist.assignedmd
    officemdLbl.text = ptlist.officemd
    roomnumberLbl.text = ptlist.room
    seenoseeLbl.text = ptlist.seenosee
    assigneddateLbl.text = ptlist.assigneddate 

}


@IBAction func ptdataTapped(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling firebase inside  `prepare(for segue:` is too late , Segue is done before data is fetched from firebase as it's asynchnous so do

```
@IBAction func getDataTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   firebaseCall {
    // inside it the segue and the data is fetched successfully 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoresults", sender: self)
  }
} 
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoresults" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! resultsdataVC
        vc.data = data // set any data here 
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

```
@IBAction func getDataTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        if HOSP != (hospnameTxt.text!) {
            query =
                Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("hosp",
                                                                        isEqualTo: (hospnameTxt.text!))
        } else if TEAM != teamnameTxt.text {
            query =
                Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("team",
                                                                        isEqualTo: (teamnameTxt.text!))
        } else if ASSIGNEDMD != provnameTxt.text {
            query =
                Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("assignedmd",
                                                                        isEqualTo: (provnameTxt.text!))

        }

        query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
            } else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let assigneddate = data[ASSIGNEDDATE] as? String ?? ""
                    let assignedmd = data[ASSIGNEDMD] as? String ?? ""
                    let officemd = data[OFFICEMD] as? String ?? ""
                    let ptname = data[PTNAME] as? String ?? ""
                    let room = data[ROOM] as? String ?? ""
                    let seenosee = data[SEENOSEE] as? String ?? ""

                    let newPtList = PTList(assigneddate: assigneddate,
                                           assignedmd: assignedmd, officemd: officemd, ptname: ptname, room:
                        room, seenosee: seenosee)
                    self.ptlists.append(newPtList)
                    print(document.data())
                }

            }

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoresults", sender: self)

        }
    }

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "gotoresults" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! resultsdataVC
            vc.ptlists = ptlists
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i went ahead and edit the code above with your suggestion (hopefully i understood) and still getting the same results. I can print the data, segue works but no data displaying on the TableView.

Comment: good morning sir. made changes to the code as noted above, unfortunately i'm getting the same results. At this point i'm doubting the way i have the TableView and TableViewCell configured. I added those to the post. Kindly please review when possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: that did it! i appreciate the help. I have updated my code above in case anyone runs into the same issue. once again, THANK YOU!!

Comment: quick question; why i cannot call the segue from a TableViewCell? made couple changes to the layout of the app and i added a button to call the query inside a TableViewCell but it does not run. thank you!

Comment: @Eddie you better post this as a question for more clarity , share it'd link here if you need a specific help

Comment: thank you. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622646/uitableviewcell-segue-to-another-uitableviewcell-does-not-run