# UITableViewCell segue to another UITableViewCell does not run - the delegate is NIL

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

**ISSUE HAS BEEN FIXED. SEE POST** 
[CustomCell label in ViewController not displaying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317277/customcell-label-in-viewcontroller-not-displaying-data)

I have a UITableViewCell with an IBAction button that calls a 
    query to Firestore. Once the Query runs i want to segue to another 
    UITableViewCell and show the data. I'm not sure what i'm missing 
    or doing wrong here. Please assist. Thank you.

**Cell Delegate**

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
func sendDataFromCell(_ sender: Any)
}
```

**PTLISTCELL**

```
class PtlistCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet private weak var ptnameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var assignedmdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var officemdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var roomnumberLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var seenoseeLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var assigneddateLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var ptdataBtn: UIButton!

var ptdatainfoRef: CollectionReference!
var query: Query!
var patdata = [PTData]()
var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    ptdatainfoRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF)

}

func configureCell(ptlist: PTList) {

    ptnameLbl.text = ptlist.ptname
    assignedmdLbl.text = ptlist.assignedmd
    officemdLbl.text = ptlist.officemd
    roomnumberLbl.text = ptlist.room
    seenoseeLbl.text = ptlist.seenosee
    assigneddateLbl.text = ptlist.assigneddate 

}

@IBAction func ptdataTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let query = ptdatainfoRef.whereField("ptname", isEqualTo: 
(ptnameLbl.text!))
        .whereField("assignedmd", isEqualTo: (assignedmdLbl.text!))
        .whereField("officemd", isEqualTo: (officemdLbl.text!))
        .whereField("room", isEqualTo: (roomnumberLbl.text!))
        .whereField("seenosee", isEqualTo: (seenoseeLbl.text!))
        .whereField("assigneddate", isEqualTo: 
(assigneddateLbl.text!))

    query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let ptname = data[PTNAME] as? String ?? ""
                let dob = data[DOB] as? String ?? ""
                let fin = data[FIN] as? String ?? ""
                let officemd = data[OFFICEMD] as? String ?? ""
                let assignedmd = data[ASSIGNEDMD] as? String ?? ""
                let assigneddate = data[ASSIGNEDDATE] as? String ?? ""
                let room = data[ROOM] as? String ?? ""
                let diagnoses = data[DIAGNOSES] as? String ?? ""
                let reasonforadmitorconsult = 
data[REASONFORADMITORCONSULT] as? String ?? ""
                let goalofhospitalization = 
data[GOALOFHOSPITALIZATION] as? String ?? ""
                let seenosee = data[SEENOSEE] as? String ?? ""
                let notestocbo = data[NOTESTOCBO] as? String ?? ""
                let comments = data[COMMENTS] as? String ?? ""
                let hosp = data[HOSP] as? String ?? ""
                let team = data[TEAM] as? String ?? ""

                let newPtdata = PTData (ptname: ptname, dob: dob, fin: 
fin, officemd: officemd, assignedmd: assignedmd, assigneddate: 
assigneddate, room: room, diagnoses: diagnoses, 
reasonforadmitorconsult: reasonforadmitorconsult, 
goalofhospitalization: goalofhospitalization, seenosee: seenosee, 
notestocbo: notestocbo, comments: comments, hosp: hosp, team: team)

                self.patdata.append(newPtdata)
                print(document.data())

            };print(self.delegate)
            if(self.delegate != nil) {
                self.delegate?.sendDataFromCell(sender)
            }

        }
    }
 }

}
```

**ResultsdataVC**

```
 class ResultsdataVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
 UITableViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 var ptlist: PTList!
 var ptlists = [PTList]()
 var tableVc: PatdataVC!
 var ptdata: PTData!
 var patdata = [PTData]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return ptlists.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"PtlistCell", for: indexPath) as? PtlistCell {
        cell.configureCell(ptlist: ptlists[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
 }
}

extension ResultsdataVC: MyCellDelegate {

func sendDataFromCell(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoptdata", sender: Any?.self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoptdata" {
         let vc = segue.destination as! PatdataVC
         vc.patdata = patdata
    }
}
```

}

**patdataVC**

```
class PatdataVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {


var ptdata: PTData!
var patdata = [PTData]()
var tableViewCellDelegate: MyCellDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return patdata.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"PtdataCell", for: indexPath) as? PtdataCell {
        cell.configureCell(patdata: patdata[indexPath.row])
            return cell
 }
     return UITableViewCell()
}
}
```

**PATDATACELL**

class patdataCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var ptnameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dobLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var finLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var officemdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignedmdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assigneddateLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roomLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var diagnosesLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var reasonforadmitorconsultLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var seenoseeLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var goalofhospLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var notestocboLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var commentsLbl: UILabel!

var ptdata: PTData!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

func configureCell(ptdata: PTData) {

    ptnameLbl.text = ptdata.ptname
    dobLbl.text = ptdata.dob
    finLbl.text = ptdata.fin
    officemdLbl.text = ptdata.officemd
    officemdLbl.text = ptdata.officemd
    assignedmdLbl.text = ptdata.assignedmd
    roomLbl.text = ptdata.room
    diagnosesLbl.text = ptdata.diagnoses
    reasonforadmitorconsultLbl.text = ptdata.reasonforadmitorconsult
    seenoseeLbl.text = ptdata.seenosee
    goalofhospLbl.text = ptdata.goalofhosp
    notestocboLbl.text = ptdata.notestocbo
    commentsLbl.text = ptdata.comments

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A segue can only be triggered from a vc instance not a tableCell instance

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoptdata",sender: self)
```

and for that this should exist inside the vc

```
 func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
            if segue.identifier == "gotoptdata" {
                let button = sender as! UIButton
                let view = button.superview!
                let cell = view.superview as! patdataCell
                let indexPath = PTData.ptdata()

            }
}
```

if you need to trigger the segue from the cell button action then you need to create a delegate

```
class ptlistCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var delegate:VCName?
   ....
}
```

and assign it inside the vc's `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = ///
cell.delegate = self
```

Now inside the cell you can do

```
delegate?.performSegue...............
```

---

a separate tip here you send `self` in `sender` which is the cell itself

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoptdata",sender: self)
```

so you can't cast it to button here

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
```

Comment: after making the changes i'm getting the following error:  'ptlistCell 0x7fe0c492a600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.' there are no errors in the compiler. i edit my code to reflect the update.

Comment: after creating the delegate in the **class ptlistCell: UITableViewCell ** but when i assign it in the vc's the compiler errors out with "Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'delegate'. I can't declare delegate on both. i'm really confused. i've been searching online and cant find anything. any other tip you can suggest? thank you!

Comment: cast it `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ptlistCell ; cell.delegate = self`