# CustomCell label in ViewController not displaying data

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, segue, custom-cell

Good afternoon, I'm running a query in Firebase and the info i get back i use it to run another query. The issue i'm having is displaying the data on the second CustomCell. I'm using the print statement and data is showing in the console. Segues are working as expected, TableViews are setup as datasource and delegate, IBOutlets are in place, Cell identifiers in Storyboard are in place too. i cannot find a solution for it, i'm not sure what i'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Cell with second query**

```
class PatlistCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ptnameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var assignedmdLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var officemdLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var roomnumberLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var seenoseeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var assigneddateLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ptdataBtn: UIButton!

var ptdatas = [PTData]()
var ptdatainfoRef: CollectionReference!
var delegate: MyCellDelegate?
var patDataQuery: Query!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    ptdatainfoRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF)
}

func configurePatListCell(ptlist: PTList) {

    ptnameLbl.text = ptlist.ptname
    assignedmdLbl.text = ptlist.assignedmd
    officemdLbl.text = ptlist.officemd
    roomnumberLbl.text = ptlist.room
    seenoseeLbl.text = ptlist.seenosee
    assigneddateLbl.text = ptlist.assigneddate 
}

@IBAction func ptdataTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let patDataQuery = ptdatainfoRef.whereField("ptname", 
isEqualTo: (ptnameLbl.text!))
        .whereField("assignedmd", isEqualTo: (assignedmdLbl.text!))
        .whereField("officemd", isEqualTo: (officemdLbl.text!))
        .whereField("room", isEqualTo: (roomnumberLbl.text!))
        .whereField("seenosee", isEqualTo: (seenoseeLbl.text!))
        .whereField("assigneddate", isEqualTo: 
(assigneddateLbl.text!))

    patDataQuery.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let ptname = data[PTNAME] as? String ?? ""
                let dob = data[DOB] as? String ?? ""
                let fin = data[FIN] as? String ?? ""
                let officemd = data[OFFICEMD] as? String ?? ""
                let assignedmd = data[ASSIGNEDMD] as? String ?? ""
                let assigneddate = data[ASSIGNEDDATE] as? String ?? 
""
                let room = data[ROOM] as? String ?? ""
                let diagnoses = data[DIAGNOSES] as? String ?? ""
                let reasonforadmitorconsult = 
data[REASONFORADMITORCONSULT] as? String ?? ""
                let goalofhospitalization = 
data[GOALOFHOSPITALIZATION] as? String ?? ""
                let seenosee = data[SEENOSEE] as? String ?? ""
                let notestocbo = data[NOTESTOCBO] as? String ?? ""
                let comments = data[COMMENTS] as? String ?? ""
                let hosp = data[HOSP] as? String ?? ""
                let team = data[TEAM] as? String ?? ""

                let newPtdata = PTData (ptname: ptname, dob: dob, 
fin: fin, officemd: officemd, assignedmd: assignedmd, assigneddate: 
assigneddate, room: room, diagnoses: diagnoses, 
reasonforadmitorconsult: reasonforadmitorconsult, 
goalofhospitalization: goalofhospitalization, seenosee: seenosee, 
notestocbo: notestocbo, comments: comments, hosp: hosp, team: team)

                self.ptdatas.append(newPtdata)
                print(document.data())

            }
        }
     self.delegate?.cellButtonPressed(self.ptdatas) //argument to pass the variable to the VC
    }

 }

}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ResultsdataVC: UIViewController  {

@IBOutlet weak var resultsTableView: UITableView!

var ptlists = [PTList]()
var ptdatas = [PTData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    resultsTableView.delegate = self
    resultsTableView.dataSource = self
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoptinfo" {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! PatdataVC
        destVC.ptdatas = ptdatas
    }
}
}

extension ResultsdataVC: UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate, MyCellDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return ptlists.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.resultsTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"PatlistCell", for: indexPath) as? PatlistCell
        cell!.configurePatListCell(ptlist: ptlists[indexPath.row])
        cell!.delegate = self
        return cell!
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func cellButtonPressed() {
    self.ptdatas = ptdatas . //this allows the VC populate the local variable                              
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoptinfo", sender: self)
}
}
```

**Second Cell**

```
class PatdataCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ptnameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dobLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var finLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var officemdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignedmdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assigneddateLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roomnumberLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var diagnosesLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var reasonforadmitorconsultLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var goalofhospitalizationLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var seenoseeLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var notestocboLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var commentsLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var hospitalLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var teamLbl: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func configurePatDataCell(ptdata: PTData) {

    ptnameLbl.text = ptdata.ptname
    dobLbl.text = ptdata.dob
    finLbl.text = ptdata.fin
    officemdLbl.text = ptdata.officemd
    assignedmdLbl.text = ptdata.assignedmd
    assigneddateLbl.text = ptdata.assigneddate
    roomnumberLbl.text = ptdata.room
    diagnosesLbl.text = ptdata.diagnoses
    reasonforadmitorconsultLbl.text = 
ptdata.reasonforadmitorconsult
    goalofhospitalizationLbl.text = ptdata.goalofhospitalization
    seenoseeLbl.text = ptdata.seenosee
    notestocboLbl.text = ptdata.notestocbo
    commentsLbl.text = ptdata.comments
        hospitalLbl.text = ptdata.hosp
        teamLbl.text = ptdata.team

    }
}
```

**Second ViewController**

```
class PatdataVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

var ptdatas = [PTData]()

@IBOutlet weak var patDataTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    patDataTableView.delegate = self
    patDataTableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return ptdatas.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == patDataTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"PatdataCell", for: indexPath) as? PatdataCell
        cell!.configurePatDataCell(ptdata: ptdatas[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
}
```

**Cell Delegate**

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
func cellButtonPressed (_ ptdatas: [PTData])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ptdatas` exists in ResultsdataVC and in your PatlistCell. In your PatlistCell this data is appended, but the variable in the ResultsdataVC is not updated.

In `prepare for segue` your are setting the empty `ptdatas` list.

A solution would be to make your delegate conform to `cellButtonPressed(ptdatas: [PTData])` and pass your generated array from the tableViewCell to your ResultsdataVC and update the ResultsdataVC PTData array before performing the segue.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, the list is empty. I just used print statement "print(ptdatas) in prepare for segue and all i get is []. Now, i made the changes you suggested but i'm getting an error when updating the delegate in PatlistCell. I'm using this: self.delegate?.cellButtonPressed(ptdatas: [PTData]) and the error is "Cannot convert value of type '[PTData].Type' to expected argument type '[PTData]'. Any ideas? thx!

Comment: A solution has been found and i have updated initial code to reflect the changes. thank you